# Is it possible to update the google Analytics Tracking object?

Tags: google-analytics

I create a google analytics tracking object like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-10303525-4', 'auto');  // Replace with your property ID.
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Later on, without loading the page, I want to update the tracking object with a userID:

```
ga('create', 'UA-10303525-4', { 'userId': response.data });
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to update or destroy/recreate the tracking object somehow?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  With a SPA we are logged out and want that page hit, but then on login, we now know the userId to associate but are not reloading the page and need to update the tracker object.  Seems like one should be able to "update" it for all future hits.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [set method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#set).

Comment: Unifotunately, you need to set userId when creating the tracker object. I just found out that you can create multiple tracker-objects. I'm going to try that now and see if that works. Here is the reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#create

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was answering the title ("can you update"), not your actual question.